# How to search for text that comes from DOM

Tags: javascript, dom

Here is how it should work.
I have an application where you have to select a sport activity.
At the moment I have a function setActivityType(String: ActivityName) that is going to set the value in my database. Now what I want to do is when I click on that button is should highlight the clicked button.
I want to do this my searching in the dom the ActivityName passed in before and select it so I can change the style of it.
This is how each sport button is made :

```
<div class="type" onClick="setActivityType('Volley')">
            <i class="fas fa-volleyball-ball"></i>
            <p>Volley</p>
        </div>
```

So how could I search for the `<p>Volley</p>` value?

Comment: You've got access to the event target in your function, you can use that to add a class to the button you clicked. It'd be more helpful for us though if you could show us what you've actually tried so far, along with providing a minimal example for us to work with.

Comment: @Lewis What do you mean with event target? At the moment I didn't tried a lot, I figured out how .children works but that's all

Answer (score 0):

I figured out to do this with `event.target` that will get all the dom information and I figured out how to manipulate it afterwards.